# How are foreign keys maintained when a related object is deleted?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, relational-database

Let's say I have two objects from two different tables called `Student`, and `School`. The `Student` table stores a foreign key for the `School` table, so it is a many-to-one relationship. Eg:

```
Student Obj (pk = 251)
- school_pk = 24 (Attribute can be null)

School Obj (pk = 24)
```

Now, what happens if I delete the `School` object with the primary key of 24? Is the `Student` object with the primary key of 251 also updated during deletion so that its attribute of `school_pk` is set to `null`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out of the box, if your database does a proper job of handling foreign keys, the deletion of the school would just fail, since there are still students referencing it.

If the foreign key is defined as `on delete cascade`, deleting a school would also delete all the students referencing it. Some databases also support an `on delete set null` option, which would update all the referencing students' `school_pk` column to `null` when the school they are referencing is deleted.

Comment: There are several **referential actions** that can be taken, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#Referential_actions